# jQuery shows wrong height ot window

Tags: jquery, height

I am using a sample code like

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
```

To get the height of window. The problem is, that I get 17px less height like really height is and it does problem. 
When I run a code from custom wordpress javascript and log it into console, I receive 920. When I open developer console in chrome, and write

```
$(window).height();
```

I received 937px. 
[image: Screenshot from my developer console]

I thought, the overflow: scroll/auto; should be a problem, but when I rewrite it to overflow:hidden; there were no changes. I also tried to use innerHeight() function, but the same problem.

Can anybody help? I am using , so there won't be a problem. Thank you for help

Comment: The new info: Problem persists in all major browsers

Comment: Maybe something was added to page between time you check in script and in console?  Or some classes changed to affect scroll overflow? 17px does sound like something to do with scrollbar though

Comment: Try adding another one in your script inside a setTimeout

Comment: @charlietfl I'm afraid that javascript is not my strong side. Could you please provide a functional code?

Answer (score 0):

opening up the chrome panel will reduce the size of your `$(window).height();`

Try to resize the chrome panel, you will receive different values each time you resize it;

Comment: Bro, my chrome panel is in another window